# PowerShell DataTable removing empty columns logic incorrect

Tags: powershell, for-loop

This is the first time that I'm writing a function that can call itself. I'm trying to remove all the columns of a `DataTable` where the rows are empty.

The code works fine but spits out some errors. For one reason or another it's looping one last time through the `for` loop with the old `$Columns` number still in memory. Although I'm filling it again each time the function is called... I don't understand why..

**The code:**

```
 Function Remove-EmptyColumns {
    $Columns = $DataTable.Columns.Count
    $Rows    = $DataTable.Rows.Count

    for ($c = 0; $c -lt $Columns; $c++) {    
        $Empty = 0       
        for ($r = 0; $r -lt $Rows; $r++) {
            if ($DataTable.Rows[$r].Item($c).ToString() -eq '') {
                $Empty++
            }
        }
        if ($Empty -eq $Rows) {
            $DataTable.Columns.Remove($DataTable.Columns[$c])
            Remove-EmptyColumns
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is it a recursive method? Try removing the Remove-EmptyColumns and it should work, no?

EDIT: Try

```
Function Remove-EmptyColumns {
    $Columns = $DataTable.Columns.Count
    $Rows    = $DataTable.Rows.Count

    $columnsToRemove = @()

    for ($c = 0; $c -lt $Columns; $c++) {    
        $Empty = 0       
        for ($r = 0; $r -lt $Rows; $r++) {
            if ($DataTable.Rows[$r].Item($c).ToString() -eq '') {
                $Empty++
            }
        }
        if ($Empty -eq $Rows) {
            $columnsToRemove.Add($DataTable.Columns[$c])
        }
    }

    $columnsToRemove | ForEach-Object { 
            $DataTable.Columns.Remove($_) }
}
```

Comment: I thought that to but it doesn't work. Once a column is removed the ID number for the other columns changes..

Comment: Your edited proposal works fine, thank you. I had to change it to `$columnsToRemove += $DataTable.Columns[$c]`, as it's a normal `Array` by default and not an `ArrayList`. This workaround is great! Thank you, should've thought about it myself ... :P

Comment: @DarkLite1 thanks for your comment.  Without the suggestion in your comment, the latest EDIT'ed answer still wouldn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought, but I like to use the String static method of IsNullOrEmpty.

```
if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($DataTable.Rows[$r].Item($c).ToString()))
{ ... }
```

This removes issues where the value may not equal '' but be $Null instead and it does it in a single line.

Comment: Good thinking, I should consider using your proposal more often. I never do it actually because it looks so non-PowerShell-native, if that is a word :D Thank you for the heads-up though!